# About choosing 2 certain different sets from a team of 5 people

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, combinations

In a group of $5$ students, students will be chosen for Chemistry and Math Olympiad, with the circumstance that each team has 3 minimum how many different choices can be made for these Olympiad teams?

My solution for this problem;

There is at least $3$ people to be chosen for both teams, however there isn't a specific circumstance that says one who's in the Maths team can't participate to the Chemistry team so;

$\dbinom{5}{3}+\dbinom{5}{4}+\dbinom{5}{5}=16$ for the maths team.
The same applies for the Chemistry team too, so;

$\left(\dbinom{5}{3}+\dbinom{5}{4}+\dbinom{5}{5}\right)\cdot\left(\dbinom{5}{3}+\dbinom{5}{4}+\dbinom{5}{5}\right)=16^2=256$ different choices. The book seems to agree with my answer however it hints to draw a venn diagram and mentions a long and meticulous solution which will be helpful in greater values for questions like these. I fail to spot that solution. What are your suggestions?

Comment: just a nitpick but in math a group has operations, here it doesn't, therefore it's a set, at most a totally ordered set.

Comment: I'll edit then. I didn't mean group of course in mathematical language i meant it in daily language but the title must change I suppose. thank you

Comment: There's only one choice if you want to maximise the chance of winning; put all five students in both teams. Sometimes its worth getting zero marks just to protest at how inane and unrealistic some maths questions are.

Comment: @JamesArathoon How can we like a comment twice:)